# pre-filter large network in cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

I'm have a large network of ~300K nodes that my machine has a hard time plotting with Cytpscape (Desktop version under Windows).

I know that the network has discrete groups that are not interconnected - I also have the id of those groups as a node attribute.

I want to be able to graph each group based on what id I select.

I tried achieving this with the filter (Cytoscape gave me the option to not plot the graph when opening it the first time - "Do you want to create a view for your large network now?") but it still seems to try to plot the entire graph when setting the filter and then clicking on "Create View".

So in short: Is there any way to "pre-filter" the graph, or to somehow else cut it up so that cytoscape will plot the one I want?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Once you have the filter set, then you need to create a subnetwork (see File > New Network), then you can create a view of that subset (or it will automatically be created if the node count is below the threshold).